# Pulling in a single name from a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

For the following code, I only want to pull in to scope of `main` the `operator==` for `Point` from namespace `boo`:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace boo
{
    struct Point {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    bool operator==(Point const& first, Point const& second) {
        return true;
     }  
}

int main()
{
    using boo::operator==(Point const& first, Point const& second);
}
```

If I just did `using boo::operator==`, this would work, but it would pull in all the other `operator==` in `boo` as well.

How do I pull in just this one?

I ask, because for the above code, I get the following error

```
source_file.cpp:18:26: error: expected ';' after using declaration
    using boo::operator==(Point const& first, Point const& second);
```

Comment: That should not be needed because of [*argument dependent lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). The compiler will automatically use `boo::operator==` if you compare two `boo::Point` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. The *using-declaration* pulls in a *name*, not a single *entity*. You also should have no need to pull in that particular `operator==`. In an expression such as `p1 == p2`, where `p1` and `p2` have type `Point`, the compiler will always search for an `operator==` in the namespace where `Point` is declared. This is called [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).